# Help finding if the proposition is the truth.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Suppose I have the propositions

$$\begin{align}
\nexists\theta\in\emptyset:\theta\not\in X \tag{1}\\
\forall\theta\in\emptyset:\theta\in X \tag{2}
\end{align}$$

which both say the same thing.

I need to know if these are true or false. What it basically says, is that for every element in the empty set, that element is element of some set $X$. But there is no element in $\emptyset$, telling that

$$\nexists\theta\in\emptyset:P(\theta)$$

must be true for any proposition $P$. Proving that $(1)$ is true.

So my thought is that this is true no matter what, but I don't feel confident about this method. Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Use `\neg` rather than `\not` to get $\neg$. It's short for "(logical) ***neg***ation".

Comment: @Hurkyl It is the same as \lnot, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true.

You can write is as: $$\neg\exists\theta[\theta\in\varnothing\wedge P(\theta)]$$
Evidently no $\theta$ exists such that $\theta\in\varnothing$.

Consequently no $\theta$ exist that satisfies the stronger condition $\theta\in\varnothing\wedge P(\theta)$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the second statement is literally the definition of $\emptyset\subseteq X$.

Comment: Good point indeed!